# Inpaint with mixed seamless cloning for error concealment in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, medical

#### Background

I want to remove hair from dermatoscopic images in OpenCV for C++ with two—not necessarily combined—desired results:

- preprocessing for further analysis using computer vision
- improvement of the optical perception (i.e. no distraction over a skin lesion)

The approach needs to be fully automatic and should - as always - work as fast as possible, though I do *not* need real time computation. Here is an example image of what I am talking about:

[image: Example input image]

The first step for this is to find and mask the hair pixels. After some basic preprocessing I am successfully (mis-)using the well known [Frangi filter](http://www2.die.upm.es/im/papers/ISBI2013.pdf) and created a binary mask for the hair:

[image: Hair mask]

#### Initial approaches

Now comes the inpainting part. First, following the idea of some domain related paper, I tried it myself using a bank of morphological operations - with barely convincing results:

[image: Hair removal with morphological operations]

Besides this, the obvious try is to use OpenCV's `inpaint()` function. The results are better, but still not perfect - and the calculation takes ages:

[image: Hair removal with Navier-Stokes]

#### QUESTION

There is the great paper about [*Poisson Image Editing*](https://www.irisa.fr/vista/Papers/2003_siggraph_perez.pdf), which has recently been implemented in OpenCV as `seamlessClone()`. In the paper, this approach of mixed cloning is also used for error concealment with promising results.

They use a manual selection of the source area for the concealment, which in my case would be some undistracted skin. However, this is supposed to be a fully automatic solution and I only know which part of the image is hair and which is not.

How can I use that simple mask to perform automatic inpainting with the seamless cloning? I could not find any direct implementation of this for OpenCV and currently I am out of ideas how to solve this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The second image looks pretty good, in this case I would propose to work in it by applying a high-pass filter. This is very similar to the median filters that are used to smooth images. But in your case you need to remove some darker pixels in certain neighborhoods. I'd use the hair mask to apply the high-pass filter in those pixels.

You can find info of the median filter [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).

Comment: I already applied a Median filter in the above images. It does some smoothing of the edges; however, with larger areas to be concealed (i.e. big chunks of hair) it will not be able to suppress all black hair color without losing the quality of the entire image.